# What does the triple question mark mean in scala?

Tags: scala

I can't seem to find what it does anywhere.
For example say you have a method such as

```
def SomeFunction(a: String): String ={
       ???
}
```

What do the triple question marks signify?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.NotImplementedError

Comment: @ipoteka Thanks, tried searching in there and google before too but the question marks made it difficult to find. Makes sense though

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`???` is [defined](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#???:Nothing) in `Predef` and simply throws a `NotImplementedError`:

```
def ??? : Nothing = throw new NotImplementedError
```

it has a return type of `Nothing` which is a sub-type of every type and can therefore be used in place of any return value.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302610/16372300 is technically accurate, it doesn't answer why you might come across ???, especially in tutorials and presentation. In the original question, SomeFunction is defined as a method that takes a single input of type String and returns a String. This is basically a stub, and allows you to continue coding using SomeFunction, but cannot run the code until you actually provide a definition that implements SomeFunction.